# When to make a channel vs just a field

Tags: ee3

EE novice here. This question has to do with best practices.

When is it necessary to make a channel for dynamic editing for your users vs simply making a channel field and simply attache that to an existing channel?

For example, if I want to make a blog, duh...I will need channel and field groups for that. However, if I just need to change headings on a specific page. Do I need to make a channel>field group > etc? Or just a field group that is aptly named and then throw that under any other pre-existing channel I already have up (this seems haphazard in my opinion)? In summary, I want to be professional (a.k.a. clear and efficient!)

Answer (score 1):

Good question. For controlling non-entry content like this, I almost always install [Low Variables](http://gotolow.com/addons/low-variables) as a sort of second admin area within the control panel. It's an indispensible add-on IMHO.

But you could also take some inspiration from the method outlined in [this now-very-old (but still relevant) piece](https://devot-ee.com/articles/item/give-your-client-more-control-utilizing-a-single-entry-structural-channel) by Ryan Masuga about using a single-entry channel for controlling this kind of stuff - especially with EE3's new "maximum entries" feature for channels.

The downside of this approach is that every channel field you add bloats the number of columns in `exp_channel_data`, and if you create, say, 10-20 fields to control custom bits of content, that's 20-40 extra columns in that table (every field gets two columns) that will be empty for all but one of your channel entries.